# Is it safe to declare an AWS Java SDK client object as static for concurrent use?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is it safe to use the same client object for multiple requests concurrently with the AWS Java SDK. For example, if I have a web server handling multiple requests concurrently and one or more of the requests need access to DynamoDB, is it safe have a static client object for reads and writes with static accessor methods e.g.

```
public class DynamoDBManager {

    private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(CREDENTIALS);

    public static void doRead(String hashKey) {
        // use the client to read
    }

    public static void doWrite(MyData data) {
        // use the client to write
    }
}
```

...or should I drop the static modifiers on the methods and the client object so that every time a web server request needs access to the database it must instantiate the manager class to get it's own version of the client.

Will there be any concurrency issues or conflicts if the client object is static? I'm using DynamoDB here as an example, but I'm just as interested in the same scenario with an S3 client.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All the clients in the AWS SDK for Java are thread safe and you should to reuse client objects.

Comment: This information is so much needed by developers. Could you please add this piece of information into the JavaDoc API documentation (e.g. by just adding @ThreadSafe)?

Comment: I've filed an issue, subscribe for notification: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/632